# UI-Router Not Going to Correct State from URL

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have a bit of a complicated set up with lots of nested tabs / views.
Here are the relevant parts of my `$stateProvider`

```
$stateProvider
    .state('tab', {
        abstract: true,
        url: '',
        templateUrl: 'tabs.html'
    })
    .state('tab.event', {
        url: '/event',
        views: {
            'event': {
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'event-tabs.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.event.list', {
        url: '/list',
        views: {
            'list': {
                templateUrl: 'event-list.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.event.detail', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/:id',
        views: {
            'detail': {
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'event-detail-tabs.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.event.detail.info', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/info',
        views: {
            'info': {
                templateUrl: 'event-detail-info.html'
            }
        }
    })
    .state('tab.event.detail.map', {
        cache: false,
        url: '/map',
        views: {
            'map': {
                templateUrl: 'event-detail-map.html'
            }
        }
    });
```

- Using `ui-sref="tab.event.detail({id: event.id})"` I can link to the `tab.event.detail.info` state and the URL changes to `/event/:id/info`, **good**.
- If I enter the URL `/event/:id` it will redirect to `/event/:id/info`, **good**.
- **BUT** if I enter the URL `/event/:id/info` the state will change to `tab.event.list` and URL to `/event/list`, **not good**.

I'd like to be able to share links to `/event/:id/info` and `/event/:id/map` but they keep redirecting to `/event/list`
Tried lots of things but can't get it to work, please help!

Edit: Made a Plunker example but I can't replicate the problem because I can't directly manipulate the URL of the app.  https://plnkr.co/edit/7iZAH26SwAILqBfkdXJS?p=preview

Comment: Have you also added $urlRouterProvider.otherwise? If yes, can you show that?

Comment: I have used it but have it commented out for the moment to avoid any confusion.

Comment: Are u sure u are not doing any url pattern matching on the server side?

Comment: @barro32 check my answer if that helps

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using this after you have defined all your states:

```
$urlRouterProvider
    .when('/event/:id/info', '/event/:id/info')
    .when('/event/:id/map', '/event/:id/map')
```

OR you can try

```
var config = ['$rootScope', '$state',
 function ($rootScope, $state) {

  //you can make the below code better by comparing URL you are hitting in the if condition. Depending on URL you can navigate to info or map state. Also, you can make the id dynamic

  $rootScope.$on('$stateChangeStart', function (event, toState) {    
    if (toState.name == "tab.event.list") { 
      event.preventDefault()
      $state.go('tab.event.detail.info', {id: 2});
    }
  });

}]
```

Comment: Thank you! I used `$stageChangeStart` to save the state, eg. `tab.detail.info`, waited for everything to load and then redirected to the desired state. Not perfect but it works.

Comment: @barro32: was'nt this question having bounty? :P

Answer (score 7):

Your `"tab.event.detail"` state is an abstract state that means the state it self can not be activated by it self so it will automatically load the child state in this case `"tab.event.detail.info"` state.

Remember: **only one state at a time can be activated**.

Refer to the documentation https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-%26-Nested-Views

Comment: I understand that and it's working as expected, the problem is I can't link to `/event/:id/info`. I edited my question to clarify it a bit.

Comment: how about if you change the 

`.state('tab.event.list', {
        url: '/list',
        views: {
            'list': {
                templateUrl: 'event-list.html'
            }
        }
    })`
the position to the bottom of the list

Comment: I changed the position of `tab.event.list` which now redirects to `event/list/info`. So `tab.event.list` and `tab.event.detail` or getting confused with each other.

Comment: the router is confused to rute the URL `'/:id'` or `/list` to `'tab.event.detail'` state or `'tab.event.list'` state so if can adjust your URL maybe change the `'tab.event.detail'` state URL to `'/detail/:id'` to avoid confusion. then try to hit the URL `/event/detail/:id/info`

Comment: Still goes to `/event/list` if I try that. I tried using regex to match anything that isn't `list` to `:id` with `'tab.event.detail', { url: '/{:id^(?!.*list).*$}' }` but that didn't work either. Don't understand why only these two routes aren't working.

Comment: It would be easier to assist if you create a [plunker](https://plnkr.co/)  or a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: I eventually got around to creating a [plunk](https://plnkr.co/edit/7iZAH26SwAILqBfkdXJS?p=preview) but I can't replicate the problem! I've had this issue for over 2 months and still can't fix it.